# unable to parse google geocoding API

Tags: geocoding, google-geocoder

In google geocoding API, how can I split the street name like `"Plymouth Rd"` as `"Plymouth"` and `"Rd"`. The default JSON format is not splitting the name and type.

Example:

```
"long_name" : "Plymouth Road",  
"short_name" : "Plymouth Rd",
```

Answer (score 1):

In PHP there's the explode() function.

```
array explode(separator, OriginalString, NoOfElements)
$str = "Plymouth Rd";
array explode(" ", $str);
```

That should get you an array with both.